# Korn shell get latest file matching pattern

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

Need help to write a korn shell script for the below.

Have to write the script in dir ..../script

Have the below files in dir ..../files

```
Have 2 file patterns 
xxx892_1.txt
xxx367_8.txt
xxx356_9.txt
yyy736_9.txt
yyy635_7.txt
```

Need to get the latest files(last created) matching pattern

xxx and yyy i.e from above xxx356_9.txt, yyy635_7  and ftp them over.

Please need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged it as linux. Is a bash solution ok?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest"? By timestamp? I don't see why 356_9 should be "later" than 367_8. Please clarify.

Comment: yes, latest created file by timestamp.

Comment: You will want to read about the `stat` command, and `sort`

Answer (score 0):

If by latest you mean time stamp.You can do something like this

```
ls -t xxx* | head -1  #this will give you the latest modified file
ls -t yyy* | head -1
```

The above will give you the file Names which you can use for FTP.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me

    #!/bin/ksh

    cd .../files

    latestFile=$(ls -t xxx* | head -1)

    echo $latestFile